# Filter query using headers in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a use case where I need to show the data of the company the user belongs to. I don't want the url to show something like: `127.0.0.1:8000/api/document?company=somecompany` rather I want to pass the company within the header and return the data related to the company.

Is there any way to achieve this in Django REST Framework? Else, how can I avoid `127.0.0.1:8000/api/document?company=somecompany`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request.META.get('NameOfYourHeader')` and set the custom header from the frontend.

Now be aware that this will real bad practise and query params are meant for this. Also if you want to filter on some user, there may be some workarounds like request.user or nested serializer from a user instance.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but, does the 'user' also get sent with the API call?

Comment: @YousufM.N yes, you can access through the request object with ```request.user``` to get the current logged in user. Maybe you should edit your question with your view/serializer code so i can give you a better idea of what to do.

Comment: great, thank you. Will try getting the data by extracting company from user.